# Clicking a Java script button using excel

Tags: java, javascript, excel, button, click

I am trying to use VBA to click on a Java script button on the following website: http://www.ura.gov.sg/realEstateIIWeb/transaction/search.action

I'm trying to get the vba to select a project and then click on the button labelled Add and then the button labelled search in the web link above.

I have managed to get the VBA to open the website and select the project, but some how I am unable to get the VBA to click on the "Add" button and "Search" button

```
Sub DLDATA()

Dim MAS As Object
Dim STYR As Object
Dim DLD As Object
Dim XLD As Object
Dim form As Variant, button As Variant

Set MAS = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
```

With `MAS`

```
.Visible = True

.Navigate Sheets("Property Value").Range("B30").Value ' Navigate to website

Do Until .ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set STYR = MAS.Document.all.Item("projectNameList")
STYR.Value = Sheets("Property Value").Range("A1").Value ' Select name of property based on name in cell A1.    

Set XLD = MAS.Document.all.Item("addOpt")
XLD.Value = Sheets("Property Value").Range("A1").Value


End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me

```
Sub test()

URL = "http://www.ura.gov.sg/realEstateIIWeb/transaction/search.action"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate URL

Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
    DoEvents
Loop

Set STYR = ie.Document.all.Item("projectNameList")
STYR.Value = Sheets("Property Value").Range("A1").Value ' Select name of property based on name in cell A1.

Set Results = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")   ' find and click the "add" button
For Each itm In Results
    If InStr(1, itm.outerhtml, "addOpt", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        itm.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next

ie.Document.getElementByID("searchForm_0").Click   ' click the "search" button 

Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
    DoEvents
Loop

' do whatever

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Sooooo Much!! At first this didn't work for me, but I added 

    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02")) before the search function and it worked. 


  Thank you very much!!